# Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is not valid beginner class

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm having a problem with the following when I try to 'Clear' the textboxes in my program. It's a beginner's class so I should be able to answer fix the error with what I've learned so far. The program is basically calculating Interest rate and the growth in capital whenever I press NextYear. When I press the "Clear" button it shows me the error and points me at the syntax `capital = CDbl(txtInitialCap.Text)` under `txtRate_TextChanged`event.

```
Private year As Integer
Private capital As Double

Private Sub btnNextYear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNextYear.Click
    Dim interestAmount, interestRate As Double
    '
    ' Assign value to InterestRate variable from text property
    '
    interestRate = CDbl(txtRate.Text)
    '
    ' Calculate new values for year, interest amount and capital
    '
    year = year + 1
    interestAmount = capital * interestRate
    capital = capital + interestAmount
    '
    ' Assign the values to the textboxes
    '
    txtYear.Text = year
    txtInterest.Text = interestAmount
    txtCapital.Text = capital


Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
        txtInitialCap.Text = vbNullString
        txtRate.Text = vbNullString
        txtYear.Text = vbNullString
        txtInterest.Text = vbNullString
        txtCapital.Text = vbNullString
    End Sub

Private Sub txtInitialCap_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtInitialCap.LostFocus
    '
    ' Reinitialise the capital variable since probably it was changed
    '
    capital = CDbl(txtInitialCap.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub txtInitialCap_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtInitialCap.TextChanged
    '
    ' Reinitialise the year variable and the textboxes
    '
    year = 0
    txtYear.Text = vbNullString
    txtInterest.Text = vbNullString
    txtCapital.Text = vbNullString
End Sub

Private Sub txtRate_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtRate.TextChanged
    year = 0
    capital = CDbl(txtInitialCap.Text)
    txtYear.Text = vbNullString
    txtInterest.Text = vbNullString
    txtCapital.Text = vbNullString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this is an old post. I'll answer in case someone else finds this. In txtRate_TextChanged, you need to check that

```
txtInitialCap.Text != ""
```

in case that text is "", you can't convert it to double